Is there a single word that means "false religion"?
I can only think of "heresy" but that is just a belief considered to be false within a religion.
is there a word that designates an entire religion to be false?

The words myth or mythology are most often used to describe obsolete historical religions, but sometimes people will use them to dismiss or denigrate a modern religion.

The words "sect" and "cult" are frequently used to describe followers of unorthodox, fringe, often breakaway religious groups, frequently led by a single inspirational figure (or prophet).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sect

Just use "false religion"  Why do you need one word?

This depends heavily on perspective. Are you trying to say that one religion is false while another is true? And is that because of the conviction in your own belief system or because the other is demonstrably false?
There are plenty of other adjectives synonymous with "false", such as fraudulent, bogus or mendacious, but you'd still have to use these with "religion" so that doesn't get you a single word. You also have words like phoney or fake which suggest that they are perhaps a copy or imitation of something that is. Any of these might suggest that you do believe in a 'true' original, so you could be presumed to be making your point from a religious perspective.
One single word often used to describe other religions as false is "pagan". Now, this doesn't inherently mean false, and some would even argue it means the contrary. But both Cambridge and Webster's dictionaries variably define it as describing any religion that is non-mainstream. It really means that a belief comes from ancient peoples who lived off the land, perhaps before most major religions existed. Some would take that to mean they must be false because they come from man rather than being god-given, which is what many regions teach is the origin of their own beliefs. Others, however, may say the older the belief the purer it is and that major religions being established later on in history is evidence to the contrary of their credibility. So, again, all a matter of perspective.
One other word used mainly pejoratively in connection with religions is "cult". If a religion is called "a cult" it is usually taken to mean that it is a small sect with bizarre beliefs and often with a 'charismatic' leader who is deified by adherents to some degree. Cults are often considered dangerous and usually some kind of pernicious fraud involving money. However, the word is used elsewhere to simply mean something has a small, dedicated following. By such a definition many major world religions could have been described as a cult at their inception.

Adjective "pagan" with the sense "false religion" has its roots in early Christianity and is thus founded in the biases of a particular monotheistic religion that proclaimed that it was the one true faith. It is not used nowadays to mean "relating to a false religion". A cult does not necesarily involve worship of a deity or deities.

@TimR The word 'pagan' definitely is used to denote a false religion within certain mainstream religions (predominantly Christianity). For example, "The Kingdom of the Cults" by Walter Martin, a widely read Christian apologetics book first published in the 1960s but still influential today, uses the term "pagan" pejoratively. So your downvote is misguided.

That's over 60 years ago.  The word "pagan" nowadays does not have as its primary meaning "false religion" --  except perhaps among the most dogmatic of Christians.

@TimR I don't know what you mean by "dogmatic" Christians. Can you provide some examples?

Here's an example: https://fraangelicoinstitute.com/2019/10/15/do-pagans-go-to-heaven-or-hell/

@TimR that's an example of someone using the word in 2019 in the way I referred to... which is counterevidence to what you claim. What I actually meant was can you give an example of what a "dogmatic Christian" is? Like, what religions/denominations are you referring to? Or do you just describe anyone who believes something you don't as "dogmatic"?

It's not counterevidence at all. I said that only the most dogmatic of Christians nowadays would regard the word "pagan" as synonymous with "false religion" though I agree that it did have that meaning in the past. I provided a link to such a person.

@timr but it's entirely opinion-based (yours) as to whether that person is "dogmatic" or "correct". You're confusing assertion with accuracy.

Simply not true. The person I linked you to is quoting established dogma and citing biblical passages that have been used to support proclaimed dogma. Um, or as you Brits say, erm, that's why they call it dogma.

@TimR "Dogma", while carrying pejorative connotations, just means an "established doctrine". We're not here to say what is true or not true when it comes to religion.

It's becoming a waste of time to discuss this with you as you're now accusing me of "saying what's true when it comes to religion".  I've only said what's true about how a word was used.

@timr the irony of you doubling down so hard on this incorrect point while trying to discuss "dogma" is not lost on me.

Then at least something isn't lost on you.

The word that comes closest to that meaning, I think, is idolatry, "the worship of false gods (especially in the form of physical representations or 'idols')".

Idolatry at its root means the worship of idols. While Christianity and some other major religions condemn the practice, worship of idols (images, statues) is central to Hinduism and Buddhism, so this cannot be used so broadly to mean "false".

@Astralbee I understand that the word has its origins in the worship of idols (as my parenthetic remark indicates) but its meaning has become broader. So your downvote is misguided.  The word "idolatry" is used to mean "false religion" or " worship of false gods" -- that you think it shouldn't be used is not relevant to how it is actually used.

It's simplistic to pick one answer, "idolatry". "Sect," "cult," "heathenism," and many others might be more apropos, depending on context. For those who do worship idols, "idolatry" is the norm.

@DrMoishePippik  It's a single-word request, after all,  and it is not looking for an anthropolgical term that observes with equanimity the various forms of religious practice around the world but for a judgmental term.  A person wielding this term unironically would believe that there was such a thing as a true religion.  Most of the time such views are held by members of religions whose dogma proclaims its form of religion the only true religion.  Perhaps OP is writing a novel that contains such a character. I don't know and don't care and I'm not making a value judgment.

Indeed, one might say that, "idol hands are the divil's playground." And the rest of the idol, too.

I think the point is if you wrote "Buddhists are idolators", would anyone understand this to mean that they practice a false religion? Or just a statement that Buddhism includes worship of idols, with no value judgement?

@Barmar I didn't say "idolators" but "idolatry". If someone were to say "Buddhism is idolatry" it would be understood as a pejorative, dismissive remark about that religion, more or less synonymous with "a false religion".  i'm not condoning the use, just providing a word that has the requested meaning.  Just as if someone asked for a pejorative term for someone of Italian descent, or Polish descent, or whatever.  Maybe they are writing a novel with a bigoted character and they want him to say something that reveals his attitudes that would be instantly recognized for what it is.
